# Client-side printing in IE6

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer-6

I have a question, is there some free libraries for client-side print from client browser which supports IE 6+ and PHP 5.2.9?

Because I was searching something like this, but found nothing=(

Comment: you mean CTRL+P ... ?

Comment: IE6? What is that? Blocked memories resurfacing.... nooo, eyes bleeding....

Comment: Who still uses IE6? Also, what does PHP have to do with printing? Also, what do you mean by free libraries for printing? The browser itself can print already....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp.

W3C (Media types) -> http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html